# Finding similarities between multidimensional datasets in r or python

Tags: python, r, similarity

I have a number of multidimensional datasets with partially matching columns.
Is there a way to calculate similarities between them?
Did some searching on google and stackoverflow, but all I could find were posts on calculating similarities between columns or single dimensional datasets.

ex) Find similarities between Data1 and 2, Data1 and 3, Data2 and 3.

```
Data1 = b  c  e  f  h
        1  3  2  3  1
        3  2  1  3  2
        2  1  3  1  1

Data2 = a  b  d  e  f
        2  3  1  3  2
        1  2  1  1  3
        3  2  1  3  1

Data3 = a  c  d  f  g
        3  2  3  1  1
        2  2  1  1  1
        3  3  2  2  1
```

Comment: What similarities are you trying to detect?

Comment: I am trying to find if I can use cosine similarity. If I can't, I will use any other I can.